# Remainders with fractional divisions not working in Python

Tags: python, floating-point, modulo

Remainders with fractional divisions not working in Python.
For example,

```
>>> 59.28%3.12
3.119999999999999
>>> 59.28/3.12
19.0
```

Is there any way to get 0.0 as the output of **59.28%3.12**

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

Comment: Another option: `Decimal("59.28") % Decimal("3.12")`

Comment: Because floating point isn't precise, but an approximation.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Though it's worth noting that the floating-point modulo operation *is* perfectly exact, at least for the case where both arguments have positive signs: if x and y are positive floats then the mathematical remainder is exactly representable as a float, and that exact value is what x % y will return.  The imprecision here comes from the conversions of the decimal literals `59.28` and `3.12` to their nearest representable values.

Comment: @MarkDickinson: Exactly, the floating point values are but approximations to the decimal numbers. `59.28` is really `59.28000000000000113686837721616029739379882812500000000`, `3.12` is `3.12000000000000010658141036401502788066864013671875000`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why, I don't know details of modulo implementation for floats, however this works fine:

```
from decimal import Decimal
Decimal("59.28") % Decimal("3.12")
```

**EDIT:** Note that you have to use quotes `"` (i.e. strings) in constructors. Otherwise it will try to interpret both numbers as floats which is the source of the problem (incorrect approximation).

Comment: Because floating point numbers are *approximations*, and `Decimal()` is a better approximation, at the cost of speed (no hardware support).

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ah, of course, it gives wrong result for `Decimal(59.28) % Decimal(3.12)` as well (note missing quotes).

Comment: Thanks a lot freakish, you made our day !